# UIButton in Background of view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm having trouble with inserting a UIButton behind a UITextView. I can make the button and it does its job well but no matter what I do, it always gets drawn in front of the textView.

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
self.backgroundButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
[self.backgroundButton addTarget:textView action:@selector(resignFirstResponder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.view insertSubview:self.backgroundButton aboveSubview:textView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:textView];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
self.backgroundButton = [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame] autorelease];
[self.backgroundButton addTarget:textView action:@selector(resignFirstResponder) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.view insertSubview:self.backgroundButton belowSubview:textView];
}
```

Comment: Still doesn't work. :( The button is drawn over the textview. if you add
        [self.backgroundButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
 you can see